# Сортировка строки,содержащей числа,не используя стандартные библиотечные функции.C++

Tags: c++, сортировка

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{   

    string path="my.txt";
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);
    if(!fin.is_open()){cout<<"File is not opened"<<endl;}
    else{cout<<"Okey"<<endl;
        string str;
        while(!fin.eof()){
            fin>>str;

              cout<<str<<endl;

            }
                       }
    fin.close();

}
```

Comment: @VVT у меня сортировка не работает,то есть она неправильно реализована

Comment: fin>>str[SIZE]; первая ошибка.  Во вторых  в строке 14 15 вы должны сравнивать не первые символы а строки 14 и 15

Comment: @ARHovsepyan ,привожу в первоначальный вид,не подскажете как сортировку реализовать?

Comment: @Harry удалила ее полностью

Comment: не использовать библиотечные функции понятно. А использовать стандартные контейнеры  можно?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообше то неправильно  выполнить задание за вас, но я решил помочь вам кое в чем. 
Во первых нужно сравнивать строки так, чтобы сравнивались и длины строк(количество цифр в числе). Для этого нужно написать компаратор:

```
bool
cmp(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    if (s1.length() == s2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
            if (s1[i] != s2[i])
                return s1[i] < s2[i];
        }
    }
    return s1.length() < s2.length();
}
```

Дальше  с некоторыми поправками ваша программа:

```
ifstream fin("my.txt");    
if (!fin.is_open()) { cout << "File is not opened" << endl; }   
else
{
    cout << "Okey" << endl;
    constexpr int SIZE = 1000;
    string str, res[SIZE];
    int n = 0;      
    while (fin >> str) {            
        res[n++] = str;
    }
    /* сортируйте массив от 0 до n 
       сравнивая элементы так: if(cmp(res[i + 1], res[i])...
       альгоритм сортировки выбирайте сами(гугл вам в помощь)
    */
}
fin.close();
```

P.S.
Было бы проще положить эти строки в какой нибудь контейнер типа `sdt::multiset` с соответствующим компаратором и получать их уже в отсортированном виде